# How to use the Wifi-LAN feature of this Chess game?

Tags: wifi, games, networking

I have downloaded this [chess application](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/chess-free/ad473404-738e-4ff6-bcdd-a0f89eb54a18) and it supports wifi lan game. I want to know how i can use this feature?

My friend and I want to play chess against each other he has an latest Android version and I have the game on Windows Phone 8. The [Android version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cnvcs.chess&hl=en) of chess app has two options of networking, Bluetooth and wifi, but the Windows Phone 8 app only has the wifi option.

What I have tried so far - we turned on wifi on both devices (Android and WP) and one of the phone chess app (in this case Windows Phone) is used to host a game (Network > Wifi lan > Host game > Ok). I see this message...

```
white: Windows phone
Wait 110 Seconds for your opponent

Start          Cancel
```

The start button remains inactive. My friend tried to join the game  (Network > Wifi lan > Join game)  but it's just showing a blank window with a cancel button.

Can you tell me how should we play this game over wifi?

Comment: I don't see anything that suggests the Windows Phone and Android versions will work together. Also, when trying the wifi mode, are both phones connected to the same wifi network?

Comment: @NeilTurner no it is not connected to same wifi network. I have never tried a wifi lan supported game!

Answer (score 2):

The WiFi LAN Game is for when you are both connected to the same WiFi network. If you're not connected to the same network, this option won't work for you - there may be an alternate game that allows playing across the Internet, but this particular game doesn't appear to support that.